# Set cookie in tumblr.com HTML editor

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup, set, tumblr

Are there any chance to set cookie for user when it comes to my tumblr website?

I'am having a pop up and i want it to show only once per visit. Is it possible with jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its certainly possible maybe `document.cookie` or `sessionStorage`. I would suggest to get a better response showing what you have tried.

Comment: It is possible I have done it on at least two tumblr accounts. You will need either some plain vanilla javascript, or jquery (the latter is my preference). Do you have any code at all, or do you need someone to code this for you? This is a very good resource: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html 

And I also recommend this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie